# Creating a custom operator - '!?' (negation of '??'). Is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, new-operator

Is it possible to create a custom operator like '!?' (negation of '??') instead of writing long expression:

```
int? value = 1;    
var newValue = value != null ? 5 : (int?)null;
```

I want to have:

```
var newValue = value !? 5;
```

Thanks!

Comment: How is `value !? 5` any different from `value ?? 5`? Because, `newValue = value != null ? 5 : (int?)null;` is the same as `newValue = value == null ? (int?)null : 5;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

You cannot create your own operators in C#. You can only override (*some* of the) ones that already exist in the language.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define new operator in C# - the only way is to redefine existing ones, but you [can not redefine ?: and ?? operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).